# How to backup app in adb without using "backup"?

Tags: adb, backup, data-recovery, broken-screen

My Nexus 6 has a completely broken screen, but other parts of the phone seem to work fine. It is rooted, CWM recovery installed and USB debug enabled. Now I want to copy some of my old data to my new phone. The problem is:

- I cannot unlock the screen since the screen is broken, so booting normally doesn't work. `adb devices -l` shows nothing since the phone is screen locked.
- CMW recovery has a touch interface, so I cannot use that either.
- I managed to enter the stock recovery mode and I can pull data using adb. But I can't run adb backup because it asks for confirmation on the screen.

Does anyone have any idea what should I do? Is there a way to backup without using "adb backup"?

Comment: CWM does have a touch interface but volume keys should also be available, which you can use to mount `/data`. ADB access should also be there by default - just plug in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying `data/data` did work. But it seems that copying the files to my new phone caused some permission issues. I fixed this by backing up and then restoring in Titanium Backup.